# parsing JSON with / character in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have problem in displaying "/home/local" which is there in following JSON

```
"Parameter":{"Name":"LocalDir","Default_Value":"/home/local","Type":"String"}
```

I need to parse and display in text box using angularjs

```
'<input type = "text" value="' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '" name="htmlComponent" ng-model="htmlComponent" ng-init="htmlComponent=' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '" class="htmlComponent" />'
```

when I tried to do this  am getting following error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'home' is an unexpected
>   token at column 16 of the expression [htmlComponent=/home/local]
>   starting at [home/local].

Comment: why do you have `+` everywhere? Did you set that as the binding character instead of `{{ }}` ?

Comment: @m59 when editing question you lost original info. OP is actually combining a string that contains `<input...` tag. And perhaps using it later to insert into DOM. Current HTML snippet doesn't have any sense

Comment: Oh my. Yeah..then something is terribly wrong about the whole thing. X/Y problem.

Comment: @m59, I'm sorry, I edited to have valid js strings

Comment: Now question to @Kandan why are you generating markup like this? Can you post the code that uses it? And which problem is being solved?

Comment: The thing is, a string of html like this shouldn't exist. It sounds like you're trying to pre-empt Angular's job. Keep your server logic and browser logic separate. Angular should fetch the json with an ajax request and then bind the data from it in the controller. If you are doing all of this browser side, then you're simply trying to manually do a lot of things that you should be using data-binding for.

Answer (score 0):

The script below demonstrates, what your code currently does:

```js
var jsondata = {
  "Name": "LocalDir", 
  "Default_Value": "/home/local", 
  "Type": "String"
};

var input = '<input type = "text" value="' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '" name="htmlComponent" ng-model="htmlComponent" ng-init="htmlComponent=' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '" class="htmlComponent" />';

document.body.innerText = input;
```

The problematic part is `ng-init="htmlComponent=/home/local"` which tells angular to execute the expression `htmlComponent=/home/local` upon initialization. The error message is shown, because this is not a valid expression.
As I suppose that you want to write a string to `htmlComponent` the right expression would be `htmlComponent='/home/local'`.

```js
var jsondata = {
  "Name": "LocalDir", 
  "Default_Value": "/home/local", 
  "Type": "String"
};

var input = '<input type = "text" value="' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '" name="htmlComponent" ng-model="htmlComponent" ng-init="htmlComponent=\'' + 
 jsondata["Default_Value"] + 
 '\'" class="htmlComponent" />';

document.body.innerText = input;
```

However, this solution is not perfect, e.g. `jsondata["Default_Value"]` is still not allowed to contain any quotation marks.

You should consider to use pure angular:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.constant('jsondata', {
  "Name": "LocalDir",
  "Default_Value": "/home/local",
  "Type": "String"
});

myApp.controller('testController', function($scope, jsondata) {
  $scope.htmlComponent = jsondata['Default_Value'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="htmlComponent" />
  </div>
</div>
```